# ”Under the auspices of” etymology

Tags: etymology

I don’t understand how the expression

> under the auspices of (roughly meaning with the support of)

developed from ***auspices*** (meaning observation of the flight and feeding of birds to discover omens).

Can anyone explain?

Comment: Hello, Brogullet.  You could improve your question by adding what the Online Etymology Dictionary has to say on this (though it's not a complete answer).

Comment: *under the **auspices** of [benevolent observer / mentor]* = *under the **watchful eye** of...* = *under the **careful scrutiny** of...* And obviously if a king employed an augur / soothsayer / diviner / prophet to look into possible futures, he'd be expecting benevolent / helpful advice.

Comment: _Auspices_, especially in the phrase _under the auspices of_, means some licensing body or director, which or who may have authority or may only supply an excuse. Responsibility is not always a feature of auspices, but officiality is. Someone may be present or have a certain role in a group under the auspices of an outside group. It's a kind of CYA word.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the two are connected. The *auspices* sis watch birds, but not randomly; they had a particular purpose in doing that: making predictions about the future. Here is what *[Phrases.org](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/under-the-auspices-of.html)* explains:

> In the heyday of the Roman Empire people were employed to ***make predictions based on the flight of birds***. These characters were known as ***auspexes*** and their observations and the token of good fortune that arose from them were called ***auspices***.
>
> Anyone who followed a course of action based on such a premonition felt themselves to be safe in their actions and to be '*under the auspices*' of the favourable omens.

So, the phrase means ***under the protection** (of these favourable omens)*.

[Grammarist.com](https://grammarist.com/idiom/under-the-auspices-of/) adds an interesting detail:

> Under the auspices of means *with the help or protection of someone or something, falling under the patronage of someone or something*. ***Certain birds were considered reliable omens, such as owls, eagles, ravens, vultures and even chickens***. When one employed an auspex, proceeding with a certain action found favorable by the birds was known as preceding *under the auspices of positive omens*.

Comment: Also looks like mistaking auspices in the present for augury of the past. If you're under the auspices of you are mostly supervised or governed by.

Answer (score 0):

OED:

> **Auspices**
>
> **Etymology**: < French auspice (14th cent.), < Latin auspicium: the action or function of the **auspex** n.
>
> **auspex**: Etymology: Latin, contraction for avispex, < avis bird + -spex an observer, < specĕre to behold, observe.
>
> *Roman History.*
>
> **One who observed the flight of birds, to take omens thence for the guidance of affairs; hence, a director, protector; and esp. the person who superintended marriage ceremonies.**
>
> 1598   R. Grenewey tr. Tacitus Annales xi. ix. 151   Shee should heare the words of the Auspices, or hand-fasters.
>
> 1647   R. Stapleton tr. Juvenal Sixteen Satyrs 206   An auspex to
> divine by the flying of the birds the future felicity of her marriage.

The logic is therefore that, in Ancient Rome, there was an occupation that foretold the future by observing the behaviour of birds. A successful marriage was desirable and therefore one consulted this person to ensure the spouse was suitable and what one could expect and how troubles should be avoided. Under the guidance of the auspex, all would be well.

Under the auspices of, e.g. The United Nations, all will be well...

Comment: I think it worth adding this to the Latin derivation.  Latin word meanings shifted over time just as they do with most languages.  First, the shift from 'avis' to 'aus' is more obviously inevitable because the Latin V was pronounced 'oo' rather than our 'V', and, before a vowel was pronounced 'w', so that 'avis' was pronounced 'awis'.  Add 'spex' on the end and 'awisspex' quickly and naturally gets resolved to 'avspex' in ordinary speech.  Semantically, too, it came to be used not just as a person who observed the birds and tells the 'client' the fated outcome. [cont]

Comment: [continued from 'fated outcome'.]  It also means not just a forecaster but an 'influencer'.  Lewis and Short's 'Latin English Dictionary  has as its second definition:  "an author, founder, director, leader, protector, favourer."  It cites from Vergil, Aeneid III.20: "Nil desperandum Teucro duce et AUSPICE Teucro" - No need for despair with Teucer in command and with Teucer as 'avspex'.  It seems to me to be a natural if at first poetic shift from passive predictor to active leader or guarantor, and (whether by translator's licence or ignorance to use the cognate 'auspices' in this way.